# Theme palette common in Material UI

Tags: material-ui, themes

I'm trying to figure out where the values in the theme "palette > common" are used around the Material UI framework?

```
common: {
        black: "#f59042",
        white: "#9a1fa3",
        contrastThreshold: 3,
        divider: "#ff0000"
    },
```